# AdMob SMART_BANNER not working in landscape mode

Tags: android

I am using SMART_BANNER in an android project. It is working properly in portrait mode but when the orientation changes(to landscape), the banner width remains same. 
This is my layout with adview:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app.backgroundColor ="#000000"
            ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxx"
            android:gravity="center" >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I've also tried `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`  for LinearLayout that contains the banner and `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for AdView - nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check there is no line like following in the maniefest -

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, smart_banner is not working in landscape mode. So change it

ads:adSize="BANNER"

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the orientation of the application AFTER the AdView has already loaded one or more ads, it will not automatically resize the view when you change the orientation.

In that case, you should override `onConfigurationChanged` to track orientation changes and recreate the AdView if the orientation changes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51349918/ads-smart-banner-arent-always-loaded-in-landscape-orientation) stack overflow question seems to have an example, but I havent tried it out myself.

In general, SMART_BANNER seems to be have a quite low fill rate in landscape mode.